# Firestore getting every field random named in document

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get every field in one document in firestore. Field's key are random numbers and values are same with keys.How can i do that with document?

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            // get every field in document.getData();
        }
    } 
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getData()` returns a `Map<String, Object>` with all the fields from the document, as you can see from [the API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#getData()).  You iterate all the fields in the same way that you [iterate all the entries in a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map).

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    // entry.getKey() will contain the name of the field with each iteration.
}
```